# Count line by searching crlf (0d0a)

Tags: c#, .net, newline

I would like to count number of lines in a file based on `crlf` (`0D0A`) count. My current code only counting the number of lines based on `cr` (`0D`). Can anybody give suggestion ?

```
public static int Countline(string file)
{
    var lineCount = 0;
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            lineCount++;
         }
    }
    return lineCount;
}
```

Comment: probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655246/how-to-read-text-file-by-particular-line-separator-character

Comment: Convert it to byte array using proper encoding. Then find any CR LF (0x0D 0x0A) using for loop.

Comment: you could use String.Split `foo.Split(new [] {Environment.NewLine}, 
               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;`

Comment: not a duplicate. most only search for either /r or /n. i need to search both together not seperated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Usage:**

```
Countline("text.txt", "\r\n");
```

**Method:**

```
public static int Countline(string file, string lineSeperator)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(file);

    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(text, lineSeperator).Count;
}
```

Comment: this is a good step however have memory constrain as it first read all line in file. I have thousand of data in one file.

Answer (score 0):

```
string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( fileName );
int numMatches = content.Select((c, i) => content.Substring(i)).Count(sub => sub.StartsWith(Environment.NewLine));
```

Note I'm using `Environment.NewLine` for line endings but you can replace with the whole string if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int CountLines(string Text)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (ReadOnlySpan<char> _ in Text.AsSpan().EnumerateLines())
    {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Benchmark:
[image: Benchmark]